# Azure service bus for embarasingly parallel

Tags: azure, parallel-processing, azureservicebus

I'm trying to use the azure service bus for an embarassingly parallel problem - one that can be divided up into N independent sections.  It is essentially a map/reduce problem, but I don't want to use Hadoop because I need real-time answers (< 1 sec)

My initial plan is to have a bunch of workers, each with 1/N slices of the database.  Then, I put N search problems on the bus and each worker would do its thing.  An aggregator would combine the results.

Am I barking up the wrong tree here?  Is this to wrong way to solve this kind of problem?

Comment: How are you planning to synchronize the N workers so that aggregator knows when to kick-in?  Also, what is an embarrassingly parallel problem?

Comment: Embarassingly parallel means it is "too easy" to parallelize:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embarrassingly_parallel  I'm planning for the aggregator to just watch for when all of the workers are don.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your general scenario is sound and one that is used daily by many who build async/parallel systems.

However, your requirement to have aggregated results in < 1s may be more problematic. Throwing messages into queues means the messages will be persisted and then de-serialized at the worker-thread end of the story. The worker thread then needs to do some work and throw results back into a queue or storage for it to be aggregated afterwards.

You might, but might-not, find that you can consistently achieve your sub-second latency requirements. Only by testing will you know if you can reach your perf & latency requirements. I suggest building an app to throw work into a queue, and worker role(s) to pull the work, do something meaningful and then return responses.

Measure, tweak, measure, tweak. Then you'll know ;)

If latency is of paramount importance and if ServiceBus cannot deliver the perf you need, you might want to consider avoiding the persistence overhead and, instead, throw batches of work-data into shared cache and notify your workers when they have work to do.

However, note that you will now have to build much of this infrastructure yourself including the worker notification mechanism, retry & mark-as-being-processed handling, etc. that ServiceBus gives you automatically.

HTH.

Comment: I hadn't thought of the service bus as being the bottleneck.  I have created infrastructure like you describe before, and I was attracted to the servicebus just because I don't have to do that.  It seems like a pretty lightweight dequeue kind of operation.  I'm not sure I could build anything significantly faster.

Comment: The ServiceBus may, or may not be a bottleneck. Only testing with a prototype will tell you.